# Find the area of ​the $AMRQ$ region

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: In figure : $ABCD$, it is a parallelogram
$MN \parallel AD, PQ \parallel AB$; if: the area of $​​RPCN$ is $20m^2$
calculate the area of ​​the $AMRQ$ region (Answer:$20m^2$)
[image]

My progress:

$BM=a\\
AM=b\\
BP=m\\
PC=n\\
S_{MRA}=A,S_{ARQ}=B,S_{PRC}=M, S_{CRN}=N\\
A+B=x\\
M+N=20\\
S_{BMR} = \frac{Aa}{b}\\
S_{DRQ}=\frac{Bn}{m}\\
S_{NDR}=\frac{Nb}{a}\\
S_{BPR}=\frac{Mm}{n}\\
S_{ABD}=S_{BCD}\\
x+\frac{Aa}{b}+\frac{Bn}{m}=20+\frac{Mm}{n}+\frac{Nb}{a}$

...???

[image]

Comment: Those two quadrilaterals always have the same area, here's why. $P$ and $M$ have the same distance from $BF$, hence triangles $PBR$, $MBR$ have the same area.  $Q$ and $N$ have the same distance from $DF$, hence triangles $NDR$, $QDR$ have the same area.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca   got a solution..thanks for hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: $QFND$ is a parallelogram so altitude from $Q$ and $N$ to $DF$ is equal and given the common base $DR$, $S_{\triangle RQD} = S_{\triangle RND}$.
Similarly, $BMFP$ is a parallelogram and $S_{\triangle BRM} = S_{\triangle BRP}$

Comment: I just posted a solution

Answer (score 1):

BPFM and FNQD are paralelograms
$ML = LP, QT=TN\\
\therefore S_{RBM}=S_{RBP}\\
S_{RQF}=S_{RNF}\\
20+A+C+2B =S+A+C+2B\\
\therefore S = 20$

[image]

Comment: exactly! btw if you see my hint, you can define area of $\triangle RQD$ as $B$ and area of $\triangle RND$ is then $B$ too - there is no need to break it down in smaller triangles - not that it matters too much. So $20 + A + B = S + A + B$

Answer (score 0):

Transform the parallelogram into a unit square, then the ratio of areas is preserved.

The images of the various points will be as follows

$A = (0, 0)$

$B = (0, 1)$

$C = (1,1)$

$D = (1, 0)$

$R = (s, 1- s)$

$Q = (t, 0)$

$P = (t, 1)$

$N = (1, r)$

$M = (0, r)$

$F = (t, r)$

Since point $F$ lies on the diagonal, then $r = 1- t$

Now apply the so-called shoelace formula, to both quadrilaterals

$[PRCN] = (1, r) \times (1,1) + (1, 1) \times (t, 1) + (t, 1) \times (s, 1- s) + (s, 1- s) \times (1, r) $

where $(a, b ) \times (c, d) = a d - b c $

This reduces to

$[PRNC] = 1- r - ts + s r$

Similarly calculation for [AMRQ] results in

$[AMRQ] = (t, 0) \times (s, 1- s) + (s, 1 - s) \times (0, r) = t - t s + s r $

But as was stated above $r = 1 - t$ , so $t = 1 - r$ and therefore the two areas are equal.